# Why is sulfur more nucleophilic than nitrogen in thiourea?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In $\ce{S_N2}$ reaction using thiourea and alkyl halide, it is the sulfur atom rather than nitrogen atom that attacks alkyl halide. But nitrogen also has lone pair, so there is a chance that it acts as nucleophile. I know that nitrogen can push its lone pair to sulfur through resonance structure, but it is same in the case of urea. What makes the sulfur atom more nucleophilic than nitrogen atom in thiourea?

Comment: In a simplified analysis, I'm guessing the reduced pi orbital overlap of C=S versus C=O means resonance structures where the sulfur has a negative charge (and nitrogen has a positive charge) become more important for thiourea compared to urea.